# css- Elements on top of each other using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get started with Twitter Bootstrap and in my practice page, the elements are on top of each other and, for the life of me, I can't figure out why. I'm not sure if it's a lack of my CSS knowledge or if Bootstrap is doing something that I'm not used to and I'm looking for an explanation of why this is happening..

https://gist.github.com/Sp33k3rph433k/6611704

I don't know if the issue is a static, relative, or absolute positioning issue, but according to the tutorials I've been following, that should keep the two elements flowing as normal, but the body content is moved all the way to the top and behind the nav element.

Comment: jsfiddle.net is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written in the official [bootstrap reference](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar)  you should add at least `40px` top padding to `<body>` so that it won't slide under your navbar.

So try to do like this:

```
<body style="padding-top:40px;">
```

Comment: Yep, dangit, looks like it was just something that I missed. Bootstrap oddity I suppose. Thanks for pointing that out for me!